# CSS: Rotate only the SVG image, not the button text, in Bootstrap accordion

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

I have the following code for a button that controls an accordion in Bootstrap; there's no custom CSS for this:

```
<div class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne">
       <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-caret-right-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <path d="M12.14 8.753l-5.482 4.796c-.646.566-1.658.106-1.658-.753V3.204a1 1 0 0 1 1.659-.753l5.48 4.796a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.506z"/>
     </svg>
     <span class="label">Details</span>
     </button>
</div>
```

In its collapsed state (when the button has the addition class "collapsed"), this renders, correctly, as:

[image: Details start]

When the accordion is open (i.e. when the button does *not* have the "collapsed" class), I'd like the svg image--the triangle--to be rotated 90 degrees, pointing down, towards the opened accordion text.

How do I do this? I tried:

```
.accordion-header .btn.btn-link { transform: rotate(90deg); }
.accordion-header .btn.btn-link.collapsed { transform: rotate(0deg); }
```

But this rotates the entire button, including the label, giving the rather awkward:

[image: Details badly rotated]

I can't figure out how to exclude the "label" from this transformation.

tl;dr: The goal is to have the collapsed state have the triangle as it is specified in the SVG, and in the not-collapsed state have the triangle (but only the triangle, not the text) rotated 90 degrees.

Comment: can you put code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this ..

```
.accordion-header .btn.btn-link svg{ transform: rotate(90deg); }
.accordion-header .btn.btn-link.collapsed svg{ transform: rotate(0deg); }
```

i have tried onhover it's working fine

```css
svg:hover{
 -ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Safari */'
   transform: rotate(90deg);
 }
```

```html
<svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-caret-right-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
           <path d="M12.14 8.753l-5.482 4.796c-.646.566-1.658.106-1.658-.753V3.204a1 1 0 0 1 1.659-.753l5.48 4.796a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.506z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: That does it! Thanks, figured it would be simple....

The image is actually starting pointed down, but then with repeated clicks it takes the correct form, but I'll play around with that.